# How to access Array on Position in android

Tags: android

I have Grid view with ImageView and TextView and show Albums every Singer when press on name album open new Activity with ListView show Every songes for Singer specific I need knowledge How do this ?
    I create GridView wit ImageView and TextView but don't know The rest please Help my
     this is code for All
  ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    String [] nameListReads;
    int[] imageId ;
    int []linkses;
    String [] nameSora;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    //Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context context,String[] nameListRead, int [] nameImages, int links[], String nameSora[]){
        this.nameListReads = nameListRead;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.imageId = nameImages;
        this.linkses = links;
        this.nameSora = nameSora;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return nameListReads.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    //Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_name_reader,null);


        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShow);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.tv.setText(nameListReads[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //     Toast.makeText(mContext,"YOu Clicked " + nameListReads[position] +"\n"+imageId[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Send  intent to SingleViewActivity
              //  Intent i = new Intent(mContext,TestShowFullImage.class);
              //  i.putExtra("id",position);
              //  mContext.startActivity(i);


                //__________________
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext,ListSoundReader.class);
                i.putExtra("id",position);
                i.putExtra("name",nameSora[position]);
                mContext.startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
    public class Holder{
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
}
```

FragmentGridView.java

```
public class FragmentGridView extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridViewImage;
   // ArrayList<Parts> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    public static String [] nameReaderList = {"محمدصديق المنشاوي","عبدالباسط عبدالصمد","الحصري","ماهر المعيقلي","المغامسي"};
    //Keep all Images in array
    public  static int[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.elmenshawy, R.drawable.abdelbaset, R.drawable.alhosary, R.drawable.almaqely,
            R.drawable.almgamsy };
    public static int [] links ={R.array.linkes, R.array.linkesElmenshawy, R.array.linkesElmenshawy, R.array.linkesElmenshawy, R.array.linkesElmenshawy};
    public static String [] nameSora = {String.valueOf(R.array.name_allSwar), String.valueOf(R.array.name_allSwar), String.valueOf(R.array.name_allSwar), String.valueOf(R.array.name_allSwar)
            , String.valueOf(R.array.name_allSwar)};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_parts, container, false);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid_view, null);
        getAllWidgets(rootView);
        setAdapter();
        return rootView;
    }
    private void getAllWidgets(View view) {
        gridViewImage = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    }
    private void setAdapter() {
            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),nameReaderList,mThumbIds,links,nameSora);
            gridViewImage.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        }
    }

ListSoundReader.java

public class ListSoundReader extends AppCompatActivity{
        private RecyclerView recycleViewSound;
        ArrayList<Parts> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        RecycleViewAdaptor recycleViewAdaptor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list_sound);

       Intent ii = getIntent();

       int position = ii.getExtras().getInt("id");

        recycleViewSound = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleViewSound);
        //Fetch the data in String.xml file
      //  String []ArrayKoran=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name_allSwar);
        String ArrayKoran=FragmentGridView.nameSora[position];



        String []ArrayLink=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.linkes);
       // String []ArrayLink=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(String.valueOf(FragmentGridView.links));

        dataArrayList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayKoran.length(); i++) {
            Parts data = new Parts(ArrayLink[i], ArrayLink[i]);
            dataArrayList.add(data);
        }
       recycleViewSound.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
       recycleViewAdaptor = new RecycleViewAdaptor(getApplicationContext(), dataArrayList);
       recycleViewSound.setAdapter(recycleViewAdaptor);

    }

public class ListSoundReader extends AppCompatActivity{
        private RecyclerView recycleViewSound;
        ArrayList<Parts> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        RecycleViewAdaptor recycleViewAdaptor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list_sound);

       Intent ii = getIntent();

       int position = ii.getExtras().getInt("id");

        recycleViewSound = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleViewSound);
        //Fetch the data in String.xml file
      //  String []ArrayKoran=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name_allSwar);
        String ArrayKoran=FragmentGridView.nameSora[position];



        String []ArrayLink=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.linkes);
       // String []ArrayLink=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(String.valueOf(FragmentGridView.links));

        dataArrayList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayKoran.length(); i++) {
            Parts data = new Parts(ArrayLink[i], ArrayLink[i]);
            dataArrayList.add(data);
        }
       recycleViewSound.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
       recycleViewAdaptor = new RecycleViewAdaptor(getApplicationContext(), dataArrayList);
       recycleViewSound.setAdapter(recycleViewAdaptor);
        }
      }  
}

How query links every Singer On the one hand ؟
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the first internet-seach match of https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=android+gridview+example : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Yes , I readed but I have another problem

Answer (score 0):

Steps to achieve this

1. Create RecyclerView
2. Create custom Adapter for that RecyclerView
3. Implement OnClickListener to ViewHolder class [link](https://gist.github.com/grantland/cd70814fe4ac369e3e92)
4. In override onClick method open new activity and show your data.( If you want click listener in activity or fragment create interface set value in Adapter and get click listener in activity.

Comment: All these steps have been achieved, but my problem is to call all the links in listView based on the name of the singer